# Verwendung von Nein nach negativen Fragen

Tags: meaning-in-context

> F: „Darf ich das nicht?“
>   A: „Nein“

Entgegen dem rein logischen Sinn --> „Ja du darfst das“ ist hier „Nein [du darfst das nicht]“ gemeint!

Warum? Existiert dieses Phänomen auch in der Schriftsprache?

Comment: Was die Schriftsprache betrifft, so werden in ihr äußerst selten Fragen gestellt, auf die man auch eine Antwort erwartet. Außerdem hat der Schreiber die Gelegenheit, es sich zweimal zu überlegen, ob er wirklich eine verneinte Frage stellen möchte. Hierzu ein Zitat von [FAQL.de](http://faql.de/sonstiges.html#verneinung): »Alle Dateien des Datenträgers jetzt nicht löschen? J/N?« – Nach kurzem Überlegen habe ich den Hauptschalter genommen, denn was nützt es mir, wenn ich zwar die richtige Antwort gegeben habe, der Programmierer aber die falsche Frage gestellt hat?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Das Problem bei einer solchen Frage ist genau genommen, dass sowohl „Ja“ als auch „Nein“ dasselbe Resultat hat.

> A: Darf ich das nicht?
>
> B1: Ja genau, du darfst es nicht.
>
> B2: Nein, du darfst es nicht.

Die positive Antwort wäre mit „Doch“ zu beantworten. Grundsätzlich besteht das Problem auch in anderen Sprachen, auch Englisch, wo aber “Yes” die Bedeutung von „Doch“ einnimmt, und somit wäre “Aren’t I allowed to do that? – Yes.” eigentlich doppeldeutig. Dazu gibt es übrigens auch Fragen auf ELU.

Anyway, die Frage bezieht sich aber auf das Warum. Strikt genommen müsste man die Frage in der Tat mit *Nein, du darfst es wohl* beantworten. Wenn in der Mathematik Minus mal Minus Plus ergibt, so sollte das auch in der Sprache stimmen.

Es wird aber mit „Nein“ nicht die tatsächliche Frage beantwortet, sondern die implizierte Frage. Die Frage „Darf ich das nicht?“ besagt ja eigentlich, dass ich (zuvor) davon ausgegangen bin, dass ich befugt wäre, etwas zu tun. Beispiel:

> A: Fass das nicht an!
>
> B: Darf ich das nicht?

Meine Annahme war, ich dürfte den Gegenstand anfassen, um ihn beispielsweise mir genauer anzusehen. Dass man mir dies aber untersagt, ist (scheinbar) überraschend für mich. Ich impliziere mit meiner Frage also eigentlich die Aussage „Ich dachte, ich dürfte das.“

> A: Fass das nicht an!
>
> B: Ich dachte, ich dürfte das.
>
> A: Nein, du darfst es nicht.

Daher ist es richtig, eine negierte Frage mit Nein zu beantworten, ohne dadurch in Form einer doppelten Verneinung positiv (=Ja) zu antworten.

Comment: In der Mathematik gilt zwar, dass Minus und Minus Plus ergeben; in der Sprache ergeben zweimal »nein« aber *kein »ja« nicht* ;)

Comment: "jaja" ;-P (Alter Linguistenwitz ;-) )