# Using doch to emphasize a negative reply

Tags: word-usage, particle, modal-particle

I stumbled upon this while looking up the usage of *doch* in "Hammer's German Grammar and Usage" (fourth ed), and the subsequent examples are from there. I am familiar with the use of *doch* for affirmative answers:

> Bist du nicht zufrieden? -Doch!
>
> Aren't you satisfied? -Yes, I am.
>
> Kommt er bald? - Doch!
>
> Is he coming soon? - Oh, yes

But the book also gives the following example:

> Mutti, kann ich ein Stück Schokolade haben? --Nein doch, du hast jetzt genug gegessen.
>
> Mummy, can I have a piece of chocolate? -Certainly not, you've had enough to eat

And the explanation accompanying it "When used with *nein* or *nicht*, *doch* emphasises a negative reply."

However, when I tried to make up example sentences to myself and ask native speakers about this usage, it did not sound idiomatic to them. Especially after considering the punctuation.

Does anyone have any further information on this? As a related question, how would one express the same sentiment (as the one meant by *nein doch*)? Perhaps by intensifying *nein*? Or something like *keine Chance* or *Absolut nicht!* ?

**EDIT:** added the translations provided in the book, in response to the comments about the second sentence.

**EDIT** The examples referenced above:

> A: Kann ich dein T-Shirt leihen?
>
> B: Nein doch. Das letzte Mal hast du Kaffee über meinen Pulli verschüttet.
>
> A: Das Hemd ist ziemlich teuer.
>
> B: Nicht doch. Es ist Seidenhemd und kostet nur 50 Euro.

Comment: In "Kommt er bald? - Doch!" ist das "doch" falsch, man würde "ja" oder "nein" verwenden.

Comment: @Robert... maybe the author was thinking about something like "doch, doch keine Sorge", which basically answers to the unspoken assumption that he doesn't come. But I agree. As it stands, especially with the "!" it strikes me as wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's a variation of "Ja doch" which is a common phrase to answer "yes" to an impatient inquiry.

Comment: @Emanuel I think Robert maybe right; I've added the translations provided in the book, and though your suggestion is the most sensible, it seems that the author did not intend it in that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verwendung von Nein nach negativen Fragen](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/verwendung-von-nein-nach-negativen-fragen)

Comment: _nein doch_ and, more commonly, _nicht doch_ are falling out of use and maybe always have been marking quite formal language.

Comment: Do you mind adding these examples you made up?

Comment: @Em1 Sure, I guess they're good for laughs :-)

Comment: I don't think the examples are wrong or bad (except for a missing article). The first one is a little... not idiomatic... but I guess with proper intonation it's fine, though. The second one is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

German has a three-form-system of answers:

> ja, doch, nein

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_and_no#Three-form_systems)

According to Duden, doch can be used to counter negative implications in questions.
(http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/doch_Adverb#Bedeutung3)

I would only accept the first sentence as a common use of "doch". In the third it might be used, but I would interpret it as being used as a modal particle.